# How to show on the user interface (Primefaces) java List<Object>

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Hibernate query which returns me List and i would like to show on Primeface's user interface different elements from the list. How can this be implemented? Thanks in advance!

This is my method:

```
public List<Object> showMessages(TRequest requestVar, Long agencyId) {
        if (!em.getTransaction().isActive())
            em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query queryMessages = em
                .createQuery("select user.name, msg.messageBody, msg.dateSent "
                        + "from TUser user join user.sentMessages msg "
                        + "where user.id in (:userId, :agencyId) "
                        + "and msg.messageGroup = :messageGroup "
                        + "order by msg.dateSent asc");

        queryMessages.setParameter("userId",
                Long.valueOf(requestVar.getAuthor().getId()));
        queryMessages.setParameter("agencyId", agencyId);
        queryMessages.setParameter("messageGroup", messageGroup);

        List<Object> messages = queryMessages.getResultList();
        return messages;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

```
<c:forEach
                            items="#{userRequestBean.showMessages(userRequestBean.request, agency[1])}"
                            var="message">

                            <h:outputText value="#{message[1]}"
                                style="width: 100px; white-space: normal; border: 3px" />
                    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: This is not of PrimeFaces at all. The [p:dataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml) is a PrimeFaces suggested solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Datatable

```
 `<p:dataTable var="data" value=" {userRequestBean.showMessages(userRequestBean.requestVar,userRequestBean.agent)}">
  <p:columns>
  <f:facet name="header">
  User Name
 </f:facet>
  #{data.name}
  </p:columns>
  <p:columns>
  <f:facet name="header">
  Message
  </f:facet>
  #{data.messageBody}
  </p:columns>
  <p:columns>
  <f:facet name="header">
  Date Sent
  </f:facet>
  #{data.dateSent}
   </p:columns>
  </p:dataTable>`
```

otherwise use UI repeat

```
`<ui:repeat var="data" value="#  {userRequestBean.showMessages(userRequestBean.requestVar,userRequestBean.agent)}"     varStatus="status">
<tr>
    <td>#{data.name}</td>
    <td>#{data.messageBody}</td>
    <td>#{data.dateSent}</td>
 </tr>
</ui:repeat>`
```